# how to select special tag after another special tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

i have a html page with some `<input>` tag that came after `<span class="class1">` i want to select all this input tags that it is `disabled`

how can i do this with jQuery selector?

i'm test `$('span.class1+ :disabled')` , but this not work !

my html is somthing like this:

```
<span class="class1"></span>
<input type="text" disabled/>
<span class="class1"></span>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text" disabled/>
```

i want to select all input like the first input (note: not like the third input)

Comment: Whats is the '+' for?

Comment: Please show your HTML and clarify which elements you want to select.

Comment: @GaryStorey The ("element + next") selector selects the "next" element of the specified "element"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers have no limit on when to stop searching. They process *all siblings* after each class1 span (regardless of any `span` between them, which should act as "fences").

Based on your layout, you would want it to stop after it hits the next span, so use `nextUntil` to limit the search and a filter to target just the required elements:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.class1').nextUntil('span').filter('input:disabled').val('disabled text box')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="class1"> span class1 </span>
<input type="text" class="" disabled /><br/>
<span class="class1"> span class1 </span>
<input type="text" disabled/><br/>
<span class="class1"> span class1 </span>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text" disabled/><br/>
<span class="class2"> span class2 </span>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text" disabled/>
```

You will note this one does not set the text of the last input (as it is not following a `class1` span.

As `@Nishit Maheta` noted (after appending my answer to his) you can shorten it to:

```
$('span.class1').nextUntil('span', 'input:disabled').val('disabled text box')
```

Answer (score 2):

use below code. get disabled element after `span.class1`

read more about [:disabled](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) selector

you need to check [.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

> Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('span.class1').nextAll('input:disabled');

});
```

Working demo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.class1').nextAll('input:disabled').val('disabled text box')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="class1"> span  </span>
<input type="text" class="" disabled />
<span class="class1"></span>
<input type="text" disabled/>
<span class="class1"></span>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text" disabled/>
```

> As `TrueBlueAussie` mention in comment i have add new option to solve
>   issue

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('span.class1').nextUntil('span','input:disabled').val('disabled text box')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="class1"> span class1 </span>
<input type="text" class="" disabled /><br/>
<span class="class1"> span class1 </span>
<input type="text" disabled/><br/>
<span class="class1"> span class1 </span>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text" disabled/><br/>
<span class="class2"> span class2 </span>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text" disabled/>
```

Comment: I think he only wants the ones after `span.class1`. I've asked him to clarify the question.

Comment: This will select *all* siblings, running past any other spans. It needs some form of restriction

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie as per your comment i have updated my answer .. check how i use `nextUntil`

Comment: Better. Had not used that variation of `nextUntil` before, but it is shorter than using a `filter`.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  hope now you are satisfied with my answer now ? Thank you for point out issue with `nextAll`

Comment: As it was just a slight change to a copy of my own snippet, of course I must be satisfied with it. :P

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie so now your answer is accepted and m happy with that . you find out issue in my code. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [Next Siblings Selector (“prev ~ siblings”)](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/)

> **Description:** Selects all sibling elements that follow after the "prev"
>   element, have the same parent, and match the filtering "siblings"
>   selector.

```js
var disabled = $("span.class1 ~ input:disabled");

disabled.css("border", "2px solid brown");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="class1"></span>
<input type="text" disabled />
<span class="class1"></span>
<input type="text"/>
<input type="text" disabled />
```